# Why the type of this e/lval is int in CIL?

Tags: ocaml, berkeley-cil

I am new in CIL and I am trying to modify an extension of CIL.

Here is part of the C code I am dealing with:

```
int main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int *p = &a;

*p = 2;

b = *p;
}
```

I am using to CIL to print out the type of lval(also I tried to print out the type of right expression)

Here is the code:

```
 method vinst(i) =
match i with
  | Set (lv, e, _) ->
    let tt = typeOf e in
      let ds_type () i = Pretty.sprint max_int (d_type () tt) in
      let i_str = Printf.sprintf "%a" ds_type i in
        (E.log "%s\n" i_str); SkipChildren
  | _ -> DoChildren
```

To my surprise, the results it generated is :

```
int
int
int *
int
int
int
```

and I tried to print out type of right expression, the results are also:

```
int
int
int *
int
int
int
```

I don't understand and why the usage of pointer type cannot been found ?

Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Why are you surprised ? The only pointer assignment is p = &a; All the other assignments are integer assignments, aren't they ?

Comment: @Anne Yes, but basically how can I find out those pointer usage? I mean like **b = *p;** and ***p = 2;**

Comment: @Anne by saying find out I mean how to pattern match those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anne commented, `*p = 2` is **not** a pointer assignment. It is an integer assignment: you are assigning an integer (`2`) into a memory location (`*p`) which is of type `int`. The fact that you specify this location through pointer indirection is irrelevant.

Your follow-up question is how to match on the type. You can simply do:

```
match typeOf e with
| TInt (kind, attrs) -> ... (* integer *)
| TPtr (TInt (kind, attrs'), attrs) -> ... (* pointer to an integer *)
| TPtr _ -> ... (* other pointer *)
| _ -> ... (* etc.*)
```

See http://kerneis.github.io/cil/doc/html/cil/api/Cil.html#TYPEtyp for more details on the representation of C types in CIL. You can also use `typsig` instead if you want to simplify the structure of the types before pattern-matching (`typeSig (typeOf e)`, cf. http://kerneis.github.io/cil/doc/html/cil/api/Cil.html#TYPEtypsig).

Comment: Hello Dr. Kerneis, Thank you and right I know that (*p)'s type is int. However, I tried **TPtr (TInt (kind, attrs'), attrs)** but I still cannot match b = *p; and *p = 2...

Comment: The question you asked originally has been answered (I believe). You should close the question. If you have another question about CIL, don't hesitate to create a separate topic. But I must say I don't really understand what you try to do: in your next question, you should be much more specific about your goal, and give the actual code that is not working (not just describe it, but copy/paste it verbatim).

Comment: @Kerneis, thank you for your reply and I post a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792166/how-to-pattern-match-this-expression-in-cil